# How can I change note on docker-compose?

Tags: docker-compose, pyenv

I am traying to run docker-compose, but an error occur:

```
eric@pop-os:~/Documentos/web$ docker-compose up Postgres
bash: /home/eric/.local/bin/docker-compose: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
```

When I run which docker-compose:

```
eric@pop-os:~/Documentos//web$ which docker-compose
/home/eric/.pyenv/shims/docker-compose
```

It is possible to change the path to docker-compose on Linux Pop Os to solve this problem?

I search on the web but not find any solution.

Comment: Compose is a Python application; did you `pip install docker-compose` in a virtual environment, and does deactivating or recreating the virtual environment fix it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DavidMaze
I try it, but in this case the error is solved, but a new error happen whit PIP, but I can't install pip. I tryed sudo apt install pip, sudo apt install pip3, sudo apt-get install pip, sudo apt-get install pip3 and tryed clone de project, but without success, because a new error occur.

Answer (score 0):

To solution this case I find 2 answers:

1. create an alias on ~/.bashrc --> but this solution gave me other problems.
2. When I installed docker-compose I installed it with pip. So
   I uninstalled it and install docker-compose again but in the
   operational system!